# aggregate sheets from many excel workbooks into one workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I want to put the worksheets from several (2-5) excel workbooks (files) into one single workbook.

The names of the workbooks are not standardized and so I opted for a dialog box to select the workbooks.

Here is the code. It meets the basic requirement that all the worksheets (sheets actually) from the selected files are collected into a single file (the `ActiveWorkbook`).

```
Sub openDialogBoxAndSelectFiles()

  Dim wb1 As Workbook
  Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.path & "\"
    .Title = "Paddington Bear Selection Window"
    .ButtonName = "Omlette"

    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

    If .Show = True Then

      Dim file As Variant
      For Each file In .SelectedItems

        Dim wb2 As Workbook
        Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=file, ReadOnly:=True)

        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To wb2.Sheets.Count
          wb2.Sheets(i).Copy before:=wb1.Sheets(1)
        Next i

        wb2.Close
      Next

    End If

  End With

End Sub
```

The code is pretty clean (I think) for the time being and pretty much fits the bill, but that's because it doesn't do the following:

If the `ActiveWorkbook` which I've defined as `wb1` has blank sheets (and a wb has  to have at least 1 sheet), once this process is done, I will have a few blank sheets left over.

So if `file1.worksheets.count = 4`, and `file2.worksheets.count = 5`, I will have a minimum of 10 (1 + 4 + 5) worksheets in the final workbook.

**Questions:**

1. Insofar as aggregating the sheets of the files is concerned, is this a reasonable way of doing it?
2. Is there a simple of ensuring there are no blank worksheets left over? Unless the input files have blank sheets that is.

Kindly,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the way you are doing this is reasonable.  Regarding pre-existing blank sheets..The rewritten code below removes blank worksheet(s) in the importing workbook, after the selected workbooks' worksheets have been inserted.

```
Sub openDialogBoxAndSelectFiles()

  Dim wb1 As Workbook
  Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

    'Cache worksheet references
    Dim originalWorksheets As Collection
    Set originalWorksheets = New Collection
    For i = 1 To wb1.Sheets.Count
      originalWorksheets.Add wb1.Sheets(i)
    Next i

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
        .Title = "Paddington Bear Selection Window"
        .ButtonName = "Omlette"

        .Filters.Clear
        'only interested in Exel workbooks
        .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.xls*"


        If .Show = True Then
            For Each file In .SelectedItems
                ImportWorksheets wb1, file
            Next file
        End If
    End With

    'Delete non-imported blank worksheets
    If wb1.Sheets.Count > originalWorksheets.Count Then
        DeleteBlankSheets originalWorksheets
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub ImportWorksheets(ByRef wb1 As Workbook, ByVal filename As Variant)
On Error GoTo ErrorExit
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(filename:=filename, ReadOnly:=True)

On Error GoTo WorkbookOpenError
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To wb2.Sheets.Count
      wb2.Sheets(i).Copy before:=wb1.Sheets(1)
    Next i

WorkbookOpenError:
    wb2.Close

ErrorExit:
End Sub

Private Sub DeleteBlankSheets(ByRef originalWorksheets As Collection)
On Error GoTo ErrorExit

    Dim displayAlertsFlagCurrentValue As Boolean
    displayAlertsFlagCurrentValue = Application.DisplayAlerts

    'Prevent Sheet deletion prompts
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim wksht As Worksheet
    For Each wksht In originalWorksheets
        If IsBlank(wksht) Then
            wksht.Delete
        End If
    Next wksht

ErrorExit:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = displayAlertsFlagCurrentValue
End Sub

Private Function IsBlank(ByRef wksht As Worksheet) As Boolean
    IsBlank = WorksheetFunction.CountA(wksht.UsedRange) = 0 And wksht.Shapes.Count = 0
End Function
```

Comment: This would certainly solve the problem. I was considering something similar but it seemed kind of inelegant. I will keep this open for a bit longer, but it might just be the answer.

Comment: In the end, the only thing I did differently is that I saved the original worksheet names as a collection, instead of the ws objects.

Comment: Perfectly good solution to use worksheet names in this context.